# CondaEnvException: Pip failed - Installing Stable Diffusion

Tags: github, pip, anaconda, conda

Hello I am trying to install Stable Diffusion on my PC and I'm following the TingTingin tutorial.
So to try and fix it, I installed git and ran the exe. The problems that others have are similar but I haven't seen the same.

I hope someone is able to help, thank you.

[I tried removing the environment and then re-creating it as well, same error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKEwY.png)

Comment: How did you install git? To a specific environment or at the system-level?

Comment: I suppose at system level at C:\Program Files\Git
. Where should the directory be sent, in the stable diffusion folder?@merv

Answer (score 0):

reinstall miniconda and it should work.